# OpenLDAP on Windows 7 not starting due to unclean shutdown detected

Tags: openldap

OpenLDAP was running and the laptop and since the battery power of the laptop did not last and the WIndows 7 OS shutdown. After restating WIndows 7 OS, tried to start OpenLDAP and get following error.

Tried to see if there is any lock or any kind of information on the internet / google search but none of them gave a good response.

```
53021aca backend_startup_one: starting "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
53021aca bdb_db_open: "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
53021aca bdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
53021aca bdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": dbenv_open(../var/openldap-data).
53021aca bdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": alock_recover failed
53021aca ====> bdb_cache_release_all
53021aca bdb_db_close: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": alock_close failed
53021aca backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=my-domain,dc=com"): bi_db_open failed! (-1)
53021aca slapd shutdown: initiated
53021acb ====> bdb_cache_release_all
53021acb bdb_db_close: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": alock_close failed
53021acb slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
53021acb slapd stopped.
```

Above is the logs from the OpenLDAP server...

OpenLDAP was running and the laptop and since the battery power of the laptop did not last and the WIndows 7 OS shutdown. After restating WIndows 7 OS, tried to start OpenLDAP and get following error.

Tried to see if there is any lock or any kind of information on the internet / google search but none of them gave a good response.

Comment: Ended up uninstalling the OpenLDAP software and installed it again. Tried to find out if there is any lock file that can be removed but could not find the same.

Comment: If you get this error

database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": alock_close failed

OpenLDAP on Windows 7 not starting due to unclean shutdown detected


Go to your LDAP installed direcotry/var/openldap-data there should be a file named alock . Delete this file . Start your LDAP.

Answer (score 4):

## Delete `alock` file

Just solved my own problem with exact same error log.
Go to your LDAP installed directory `/var/openldap-data`
there should be a file named `alock` . Delete this file . Start your LDAP.
You are welcome.

Also try this , from : http://www.zytrax.com/

> select the dos window in which it is running and type CTRL-C, the server will stop and you will be offered a prompt Terminate Batch Job?, typing `y` to this prompt will close the window.
>
> If this procedure is not followed (for example you closed your PC
> without terminating the LDAP server) the server will probably
> subsequently refuse to start. If this is the case navigate to the
> directory `c:\openldap\var\run` and delete any files in this directory
> (`slapd.args` and `slapd.pid`). The server should now restart. Failing
> this look at the log file (default in `\var\log`).